# Check If URL Can Match React Router Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Given an arbitrary URL, is there a way to check if this URL *could* be routed via the React Router using a `<Link>` tag instead of an `<a>`?

My organization is building a component library of common UI elements. This component library is built using Storybook and React. The component library will be consumed by a number of applications, some completely developer driven and others that are more "CMS" orientated that allow users to add HTML (including links inside a rich text editor) to certain parts of the website.

While links inside code are easy to identify either needing to be `<Link>` for application URLs, or for external URLs or URLs that point to static assets on the same domain, an `<a>` is required.

However, for user generated content, they may input a URL such as `https://example.org/some-route-here`. This URL could fall under 4 categories :

1. The rendering of the component could be outside of a `<Router>` anyway, in which case we check if we are inside a Router Context and if not, we *always* render a `<a>`
2. The URL could be an external domain, in which case an `<a>` should be rendered in React.
3. The URL could be for the same domain we are on, and could be a URL that could be routed via React, in which case we should render `<Link>`
4. The URL could be for the same domain we are on, but the link is to a static asset (A document, image etc), in which case a `<a>` is needed.

1 and 2 are easy enough to check. 3 and 4 seem to be tripping us up quite a bit.

An additional caveat is that we do not know the consumer of the library, so rule based configuration (For example, if a URL starts with /assets, always use `<a>` would be hard to enforce).

I was expecting some (pesudo) code such as :

```
import { Router } from '@react/router';

if(Router.hasEntry(window.location.path)) { 
    return '<Link>'
} else { 
    return '<a>'
}
```

However I don't think there exists a way to get a singleton/static instance of all router routes, nor anyway to check arbitrarily if a route *could* be routed by ReactRouter.